# How to upgrade dataTables to 1.10.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

It is a well defined scripted table. Many are using it and here comes an upgrade of it. But after following the link http://www.datatables.net/upgrade/1.10 I ran up in errors like: 
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '128' in

```
at isArraylike (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.js:997:65)
at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.js:632:14)
at _fnCamelToHungarian (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js:359:5)
at _fnColumnOptions (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js:635:4)
at http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js:6351:5
at _fnApplyColumnDefs (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js:967:5)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js:6350:4)
at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.js:657:23)
at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.js:266:17)
at DataTable (http://amgarg-w7:8080/Altius/akshajai/app/lib/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js:6041:8) <table my-table="overrideOptions" aa-table-data="stringTable" aa-data="stringSearchTable" ao-column-defs="columnDefs" fn-row-callback="myCallback" class="dataTable table table-bordered table-striped2 table-hover" id="table_report">
```

Comment: The solution I found is to modify the function _fnCamelToHungarian(). It was was erroring because it was finding the prototype methods in the _hungarianMap and trying to get the charAt[0]. Solved this problem by changing the method to only look at enumerable types using Object.keys(user).

The modified part of code is as follows:
function _fnCamelToHungarian ( src, user, force )
{...
/** MODIFIED **/
$.each(/*user*/ Object.keys(user), function (key, val) {
           hungarianKey = src._hungarianMap[ val ];
        ...
Instead of getting object name (user), now we got all its keys in it.

Comment: You could post your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted - perhaps helping other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to modify the function _fnCamelToHungarian(). It was was erroring because it was finding the prototype methods in the _hungarianMap and trying to get the charAt[0]. Solved this problem by changing the method to only look at enumerable types using Object.keys(user). The modified part of code is as follows:

function _fnCamelToHungarian ( src, user, force ) 
{...
...
...
    /** MODIFIED **/ 
    $.each(/*user*/ Object.keys(user), function (key, val) { 
    hungarianKey = src._hungarianMap[ val ]; 
    ... 
    }
...
}
Instead of getting object name (user), now we got all its keys in it.